# Best practice on Azure and access controls

Tags: azure, rbac

I need to give a colleague access to a development azure portal so that he can learn how to create web bots. As he has no experience of azure, I dont want to through him in the deep end, so would rather use RBACs, but I cant quite see what roles would be best to apply. I had been thinking about creating a resource group and then scoping the 'contributor' role assignment to the group, but would like to try to find a more granular approach where the type of resources the user can create are restricted eg excluding VMs and SQL server?

Answer (score 0):

When you [deploy a bot, typically these resources](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/bot-service/bot-builder-deploy-samples?view=azure-bot-service-4.0&tabs=csharp) are created in the Azure portal:

Resources

- Web App
- App Service
- App Service plan
- Application Insights
- Storage account

If you wanted to get really granular, you could make your colleague these [built-in roles](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/role-based-access-control/built-in-roles) as these are the typical services deployed with a bot:

- Web Plan Contributor
- Website Contributor
- Storage Account Contributor
- Application Insights Component Contributor

Another approach would be to go the Resource Group route and assign a policy to audit the creation of services so you can give your college more room to test

Comment: I'll go with the second approach as the first is a bit too restrictive. Many thanks !